# WinSCP SSIS - Capture Exit Code in a Variable

Tags: ssis, winscp

I have an SSIS package that executes the WinSCP.exe via execute process task.
All works well.
However, i am working on a logging routine for the files that were successfully/unsuccessfully downloaded and i have a header and detail logging table to capture the data.

Is there a way in the execute process task to have the exit code returned into a variable?

Thanks

Comment: You should explain how/what for you want to use the exit code as the solutions may vary depending on this.

Comment: I simply want to log the exit code in my session header table for job success/failure statistics that we can report back to our vendors with.